# What is the best way to get data from table (Many to Many Self Join) Hibernate?

Tags: sql, database, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a table to save `Friendship` of 2 people.
So, in `Friendship` I have `person_a_id` and `person_b_id`.
It's clearly a relationship many to many of the table `Person`.

With SQL, we can have simple way to get all friends of a person by using **select** and **join**.

The problem is while I'm using Hibernate (Spring boot). I used this instruction https://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/hibernate4/ManytoManySelfJoin.shtml

It's `many to many` connection between 2 tables. But they don't show how to get data back from the table.

Can anyone show me how to complete it? Or a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should create new table which will hold the linking between Friendship and Person table .
Table Person_FriendShip
columns = person_id,friendship_id

When defining entity you should add

```
Person Entity class:
@ManyToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
name="Person_FriendShip",
joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="person_id"),
inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="friendship_id"))
Set<FriendShip> friendships=new Hashset<>();

in Friendship Entity Class:
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="friendship")
Set<Person> persons=new HashSet<>();
```

This will make M2M relation between 2 entities and will have required  data when you use it with JPA Repo.

Comment: But how can we get the data from the table `Person_Friendship`?

Comment: when you to select on Person then it will have it for you as its join . You can debug the code , you will find the data within class and then you can use stream api to filter it

Answer (score 0):

Using the linked Faculty example as you haven't shown your entities you could eagerly fetch coworkers and colleagues something like this

```
    // Assume Faculty with Id=1 exists
    Faculty faculty = entityManager.createQuery(
                    "SELECT c FROM Faculty c " +
                            "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.coworkers " +
                            "LEFT JOIN FETCH c.colleagues " +
                            "WHERE c.facultyId = :facultyId", Faculty.class)
            .setParameter("facultyId", 1L)
            .getSingleResult();
```

Bear in mind that fetching multiple collections in a single query can be less than performant and if the collections were Lists you would get a MultipleBagFetchException